# Nested closure resolution different between methods and properties?

Tags: groovy, closures

When a closure's resolveStrategy is set to `DELEGATE_ONLY` or `DELEGATE_FIRST`, resolution is different in nested closures between methods and properties of the delegate.  For example, in the following, `x` resolves to `f`'s delegate (what I expect), but `keySet()` resolves to `g`'s delegate.

```
​def g = {->
    def f = {
        {-> [x, keySet()]}()
    }

    f.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
    f.delegate = [x: 1, f: 0]

    f()
}      

g.delegate = [x: 0, g: 0]
g()
```

​
Result: `[1, ['x', 'g']]`

Whereas without the nested closure

```
def g = {->
    def f = {
        [x, keySet()]
    }

    f.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
    f.delegate = [x: 1, f: 0]

    f()
}      

g.delegate = [x: 0, g: 0]
g()
```

Result: `[1, ['x', 'f']]`

Is this behavior expected and documented somewhere?  Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is a bug. If you change the map for a `Expando` it behaviors differently:

```
f = {
  g = {
    { -> keySet() }()
  }

  g.delegate = new Expando(a: 1000, b: 900, c: 800, keySet: { 'g keyset' })
  g.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
  g()

}

f.delegate = new Expando(a: 90, x: 9, y: 1, keySet: { 'f keyset' })

assert f() == 'g keyset'




f = {
  g = {
    { -> keySet() }()
  }

  g.delegate = [a: 1000, b: 900, c: 800]
  g.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_ONLY
  g()

}

f.delegate = [a: 90, x: 9, y: 1]

assert f().toList() == ['a', 'b', 'c'] // fails :-(
```

Maybe filling a [JIRA](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY)?

Comment: New home for the Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7232

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a workaround if you never want to fall through to the owner (ie, `DELEGATE_ONLY`): you can set both the delegate and the owner to the same value:

```
def g = {->
    def f = {
        {-> [x, keySet()]}()
    }

    def d = [x: 1, f: 0]
    f = f.rehydrate(d, d, f.thisObject)

    f()
}      

g.delegate = [x: 0, g: 0]
g()
```

Result: `[1, ["x", "f"]]`

Note that `f.owner = d` does not work: while there is no error, it seems to be a no-op.  You must use `rehydrate`.