# Groovy resolveStrategy in nested closure

Tags: groovy

I am puzzling over Groovy delegation strategy in nested closures. Here is a simplified example:

```
class Clazz {
    String name
    String whoAmI() {
        return name
    }
    void doit(Clazz clazz) {
        def cl = {
            println "Outer closure: resolveStrategy=${resolveStrategy}, " +
                    "implicit=${whoAmI()}, delegated=${delegate.whoAmI()}"
            {->
                println "Inner closure: resolveStrategy=${resolveStrategy}, " +
                        "implicit=${whoAmI()}, delegated=${delegate.whoAmI()}"
            }.call()
        }
        cl.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        cl.delegate = clazz
        cl()
    }
}
    
def a = new Clazz(name: 'A')
def b = new Clazz(name: 'B')
a.doit(b)
```

Output:

> Outer closure: resolveStrategy=1, implicit=B, delegated=B
>
> Inner closure: resolveStrategy=0, implicit=A, delegated=B

Why doesn't **resolveStrategy** propagate to the inner closure? The point of setting resolution strategy is to change the way implicit *this* is resolved. But if it doesn't propagate inside closures, then the mechanism seems to be as good as useless. Closures are so ubiquitous in Groovy that you can hardly write a couple of lines without them.

Answer (score 1):

Found a similar question from almost five years ago: [Nested closure resolution different between methods and properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27627463/nested-closure-resolution-different-between-methods-and-properties) Apparently it's a bug, and it has been open without any movement since then: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7232

The linked post notes something I also noticed: properties are correctly resolved to the delegate, but not method calls. Here is a reworked example to demonstrate this:

```
class Clazz {
    String name

    void doit(Clazz clazz) {
        def cl = {
            println "Outer closure: property=${name}, method=${getName()}"
            {->
                println "Inner closure: property=${name}, method=${getName()}"
            }.call()
        }
        cl.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        cl.delegate = clazz
        cl()
    }
}

def a = new Clazz(name: 'A')
def b = new Clazz(name: 'B')
a.doit(b)
```

Result:

```
Outer closure: property=B, method=B
Inner closure: property=B, method=A
```

Someone in the linked post posted a workaround using *rehydrate*. In my case though it works (sort of) only if *all* references are replaced, including *this*!

```
class Clazz {
    String name

    void doit(Clazz clazz) {
        def cl = {
            println "Outer closure: property=${name}, method=${getName()}"
            {->
                println "Inner closure: property=${name}, method=${getName()}"
            }.call()
        }
        cl.rehydrate(clazz, clazz, clazz)()
    }
}

def a = new Clazz(name: 'A')
def b = new Clazz(name: 'B')
a.doit(b)
```

Result:

```
Outer closure: property=B, method=B
Inner closure: property=B, method=B
```